# Append content to JSON Array (i.e. replacing the last ']' character) with pure Bash without reading the whole line into memory

Tags: bash

Consider a data file where each line contains verly large JSON Arrays with numbers, e.g.

```
[123,456,789,100.12]
....
[456,1231,1231,55,11]
```

There is always at least one line in the file and each line ends with a newline character (even the last one).

How do I add a single number to the last array with just Bash (v3.x) without requiring any additional tools except for those that are contained in [Busybox](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html). As the lines can grow quite large, I would prefer a solution which does not involve reading the whole line into RAM and just removes the newline and ']' character, appends the number and re-adds the 2 removed characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `truncate` command to remove the last 2 characters ondisk:

```
➜ cat test
[123,456,789,100.12]
....
[456,1231,1231,55,11]

➜ truncate -s-2 test && echo ",12]" >> test

➜ cat test
[123,456,789,100.12]
....
[456,1231,1231,55,11,12]
```

You may need to adjust the truncate parameter depending on the amount of newlines trailing you have.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the number in a variable, use `sed`

```
var=10;
sed -i "\$s/]$/,${var}]/" jsonfile
```